# Automatically generate playlist with php

Tags: php

I generate a playlist with following script:

```
   <?php 
$dir        = './music';
$url        = 'music';

header('Content-type: text/xml');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' . "\n";
echo '<playlist>';
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    $dp = opendir($dir);
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($dp))){       
        if ('mp3'==strtolower(substr($file, -3))) {                     
            printf('<sound src="%s/%s" stream="true" soundbuffer="8">%s</sound>', $url, $file, str_replace('_', ' ', substr($file, 0, -4)));
            echo "\n";
        }        
    }
    closedir($dp);
}
echo '</playlist>';
```

**How do I get the artist and length from each mp3 file?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: you dont actually need those tags for it to work in case you didnt realise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse the file and extract the data. It can't give you any more info as you haven't indicated the ID3 version (and there are several). [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3) has information on the diffrences between ID3v1 and v2

A better option would be to use a library, something like [ID3](http://php.net/manual/en/book.id3.php) or [getID3](http://getid3.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this library.

http://getid3.sourceforge.net/

That will get you the artist and the title as well as length.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this site also

http://www.refdev.com/free_scripts/PHP/Audio_Management/

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this function here to read mp3 id3 tags:

> http://www.barattalo.it/2010/02/22/reading-mp3-informations-with-php-id3-tags/